# Download file from Amazon S3 with lumen/php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lumen

According to the resource given in the AWS documentation, downloading object can be done with the following code:

```
public function download($folder, $file)
    {
        $s3 = new S3Client([
            'region'  => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'version'=>'latest',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    =>env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' =>env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
            ],
        ]);
        $result = $s3->getObject([
            'Bucket'                     => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'Key'                        => $folder.'/'.$file,
            'ResponseContentType'        => 'text/plain',
            'ResponseContentLanguage'    => 'en-US',
            'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename='.$file,
            'ResponseCacheControl'       => 'No-cache',
            'ResponseExpires'            => gmdate(DATE_RFC2822, time() + 3600),
        ]);
        header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
        echo $result['Body'];
    }
```

According the docs the above code should display a pdf file (in my case), it opens a pdf but says

> Failed to load PDF document.

The file is the s3 don't have any issue, I know it the code. But what can I do to the browser to read and also download automatically?

For detail info, I followed this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.html and went to using AWS SDKs

**EDIT**

I changed `'ResponseContentType' => 'plain/text'` to `'ResponseContentType' => 'application/pdf'`, it opened the pdf but now I need to download it

Comment: Check what content type is getting set while uploaded object into S3

Answer (score 0):

This should most likely be:

```
'ResponseContentType' => 'application/pdf',
```

Else it will be transferred as text and will result in a corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding header in the code like below solved my issue:

```
public function download($folder, $file)
    {
        $s3 = new S3Client([
            'region'  => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'version'=>'latest',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    =>env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' =>env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
            ],
        ]);
        $result = $s3->getObject([
            'Bucket'                     => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'Key'                        => $folder.'/'.$file,
            'ResponseContentLanguage'    => 'en-US',
            'ResponseCacheControl'       => 'No-cache',
            'ResponseExpires'            => gmdate(DATE_RFC2822, time() + 3600),
        ]);
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file);
        header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
        echo $result['Body'];
    }
```

I already wrote on **EDIT** that changing `'ResponseContentType' => 'plain/text'` to `'ResponseContentType' => 'application/pdf'` opened the pdf but I choose to not include `ResponseContentType` on my code so that it can it any file type.